# Querying a List of Objects From Firebase

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3

Been looking all over for an answer to this. Maybe I'm blind but I didn't find any sufficient answers for Typescript.

I have a list of objects in Firebase that I need to query. Im pushing the data onto what I thought was a list, pretty much like this:

```
this.afDB.list(`users/${auth.uid}/events`).push(data);
```

I then have this to query it:

```
   var eventsByUser = this.rootRef.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('events').orderByChild('name');
     eventsByUser.on('value', snap => {
     this.events.push(snap.val());
     console.log(this.events[0]);
   })
```

And the output of the query is like this:

```
{
    -KxVJah-5OzL029wq8p5: {date: "2017-10-28", description: "rg", name: "new event"},
    -KxVJbLt6ZcO8OpIomcO: {date: "2017-10-28", description: "rg", name: "new event 2"}, 
    -KxVJbqx4cSN5YqhxvZ4: {date: "2017-10-28", description: "rg", name: "new event 3"}
}
```

It's not in a list; its returning an object of objects instead of a list of objects. Therefore I can't just index through it without using the keys, such as:`-KxVJbLt6ZcO8OpIomcO`. How do I get around this problem so I can access each object? I'm not too keen on the Firebase API.

Comment: have you tried using `this.afDB.object()`

Comment: @krv you mean something like this?
  `this.afDB.object(path/to/node).push(data);`

Comment: yes. Check the github repo docs for more on this.

Comment: @krv looked but didn't find much. Docs are not organized very well.